Document search with Azure OpenAI and FAISS is not working
I am trying to create vector index using FAISS but I am either gettingerror :
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'create'
OR
NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}}
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key="7b40009xxxxxx2748axxxxxx5553c1a", model='text-embedding-3-small', deployment='Oasis-embedding-3-small', client="azure", chunk_size=10)

#Define the texts you want to add to the FAISS instance
texts = ["FAISS is an important library", "LangChain supports FAISS"]
faiss = FAISS.from_texts(texts, embeddings)

===================================================================
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'create'
tried several alternate.... but no luck
from langchain.document_loaders.pdf import PyPDFLoaderloader = PyPDFLoader("./data/machine_learning_yearning_by_andrew_ng.pdf")pages= loader.load_and_split()from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

embedder = OpenAIEmbeddings(api_key='7b4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx83c915553c1a',model='text-embedding-3-small',deployment='Oasis-embedding-3-small',api_version="2024-02-01",base_url="https://xxxxxxxxxx.openai.azure.com/")

OpenAIEmbeddings(client=\<openai.resources.embeddings.Embeddings object at 0x000001E57E40DDD0\>, async_client=\<openai.resources.embeddings.AsyncEmbeddings object at 0x000001E57E42C210\>, model='text-embedding-3-small', deployment='Oxxxx-embedding-3-small', openai_api_version='2024-02-01', openai_api_base='https://oxxxxxxxxx.openai.azure.com/', openai_api_type='Azure', openai_proxy='', embedding_ctx_length=8191, openai_api_key='7b4xxxxxxxxxxxxx915553c1a', openai_organization=None, allowed_special=set(), disallowed_special='all', chunk_size=1000, max_retries=2, request_timeout=None, headers=None, tiktoken_enabled=True, tiktoken_model_name=None, show_progress_bar=False, model_kwargs={}, skip_empty=False, default_headers=None, default_query=None, retry_min_seconds=4, retry_max_seconds=20, http_client=None)

Error:
faiss_index = FAISS.from_documents(pages, embedder)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'create'

\['FAISS is an important library', 'LangChain supports FAISS'\]

NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}}

I am using Jupiter Note book...
I am new to OpenAI, Please help me to make it working thefaiss_index = FAISS.from_documents(pages, embedder)orfaiss_index = FAISS.from_texts(pages, embedder)What is am missing ? Any working sample with Azure OpenAI DocumentSearch plz....

You would have to decide what to load into FAISS vectorDB, FAISS.from_texts or FAISS.from_documents
The last error message shows that you were trying to use FAISS.from_documents. You may want to check the document at
https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/vectorstores/langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss.FAISS.html#langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss.FAISS.from_documents
And here's the code I slightly modified
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
loader = PyPDFLoader("./data/machine_learning_yearning_by_andrew_ng.pdf")
pages = loader.load_and_split()
# pages = loader.load()
# print(pages)

# from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
faiss_index = FAISS.from_documents(pages, embeddings)
    
print(faiss_index)


Still Error is there:
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key="7b400095faxxxxxxxxxx553c1a", model='text-embedding-3-small',
deployment='Oasis-embedding-3-small', client="azure", chunk_size=10)
#Define the texts you want to add to the FAISS instance
texts = ["FAISS is an important library", "LangChain supports FAISS"]
faiss = FAISS.from_texts(texts, embeddings)
Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'create'

from langchain.document_loaders.pdf import PyPDFLoader
loader = PyPDFLoader("./data/machine_learning_yearning_by_andrew_ng.pdf")
pages= loader.load_and_split()
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
faiss_index = FAISS.from_documents(pages, embeddings)
print(faiss_index)
error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'create'

Again, I truncated the used part in the code, according to yours. It runs well and the error can not be reproduced. Can you try it again?
